# Google Cloud public hostname

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

Is there any solution to get a public hostname in google cloud like in other cloud platforms?
Currently the machine name is:
computername.c.googleprojectid.internal

but I want something like in Amazon or in Azure:
computername.cloudapp.net

Comment: Ok sorry I found it: computername.c. googleprojectid.googleapis.com

Comment: It looks like *.googleapis.com is a CNAME to googleapis.l.google.com., which is a Google load-balanced name for googleapis.com.  I don't think that will match your GCE computer's external IP address.

Comment: @user3296520 where did you found that? or how can I find it for my instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Google Cloud DNS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/) service to update the DNS record for your host on startup.  (You could also use a service like dyn-dns, but I'm assuming that you want to us the Google tools where possible.)  It looks like you'd want to use the ["create change" API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/api/v1beta1/), using a service account associated with your VM.  This would look something like:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1beta1/projects/*myProject*/managedZones/*myZone.com*/changes

{
  "additions": [
    {
      "name": "computername.myZone.com.",
      "type": "A",
      "ttl": 600,
      "rrdatas": [
        "200.201.202.203"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "deletions": [
  ],
}
```

Note that 200.201.202.203 needs to be the external IP address of your VM.